# JavaFX Italic Font w/CSS

Tags: css, javafx, javafx-8

I'm using a CSS style sheet with a style class like this:

```
.sublabel {
    -fx-font-style: italic; 
    -fx-font-size: 12;
}
```

...which has been set as the Label's Style Class in Scene Builder. The font size changes as expected (smaller, since I have -fx-font-size: 14; under the .root class but this is the only font-related setting). Bold style works fine, but it refuses to use an italic font. I'm not using a custom font anywhere, so this should be using the default font JavaFX 8 uses on Win7. I've also tried setting it under Style independently.

What could cause the style request to be ignored?

Comment: You should add the accompanying java code. `.sublabel` is a class, is this what you intended? Did you apply the class correctly to the label?

Comment: I would imagine I did at the time, since I said above that "bold style works fine" (if you change italic to bold). Doubt there was any code to show, it was done in Scene Builder.

Answer (score 3):

The default font in JavaFX, "system", does not support italic. You can even choose italic in SceneBuilder, but it will only work for fonts that support it.

Try using a TrueType font, e.g. Verdana, then it should work without problems.

Either use the style version below, or the more direct: Font name="Verdana Italic"

```
<Button style="-fx-font-style: italic;" text="Button">
    <font>
        <Font name="Verdana"/>
    </font>
</Button>
```

Comment: Makes sense. But now I'm going to throw another wrench in. I just tried replicating this on Linux (Mint) without setting any font (it was just "system"). Italics worked fine! Maybe it's some OS level difference...

Comment: Of course this is also with Java 17, not sure what version I used back in 2018.